# I use mybatis in java API, it daily stop automatically, after restart works properly

Tags: java, mybatis

I use java API with mybatis for insert multiple data at a time in DB. It works
  properly but service daily stop automatically on web logic
  server.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that java web service not working next day without restart. So it is mybatis issue or another ???

Comment: `service not working` is not very descriptive and does not help to understand the problem. What exactly does not work?

Comment: there are multiple methods in the package i/e GET,INSERT AND UPDATE....at a particular time interval when servers are under maintenance the insert and update methods stops working after this schedule although the get methods still works,Once i restart the service on server insert and update mehtods starts working back to normal.I dont if there are some stuck threads or something in the code that requires restart of the service every 24 hours

Comment: this is probably not problem with mybatis but with your server setup (or whatever you use). You need to provide more information about the whole setup, so I suggest you to edit your question and include details.

Answer (score 0):

My service code files are as follows -

(1) Action Method class -

```
public void insertListDetails(){


ObjectMapper jsonObjMapper = new ObjectMapper();

jsonObjMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);




    SqlSession sqlSession = null;

    String responseStr = null;

    List<String> list_desc = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list_status = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list_remark = new ArrayList<String>();

    list_desc.add(description);
    list_status.add(status);
    list_remark.add(remark);


    String descSeprated = "";
    String statusSeprated = "";
    String remarkSeprated = "";

    response.setContentType("application/json");


try {



        ServerResponse<String> serverResponse = new ServerResponse<String>();
        boolean isError = false;



        if (!isError) {

            try {
                sqlSession = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();


                InsertListMappers apiMapper = 
                sqlSession.getMapper(InsertListMappers.class);

                InsertList apiDetail = new InsertList();


                for (String string_1 : list_desc) {
                    if (descSeprated.equals("")) {
                        descSeprated = string_1;
                    } else
                        descSeprated = descSeprated + "#" + string_1;
                }
                for (String string_2 : list_status) {
                    if (statusSeprated.equals("")) {
                        statusSeprated = string_2;
                    } else
                        statusSeprated = statusSeprated + "#" + string_2;
                }
                for (String string_3 : list_remark) {
                    if (remarkSeprated.equals("")) {
                        remarkSeprated = string_3;
                    } else
                        remarkSeprated = remarkSeprated + "#" + string_3;
                }



                String[] data_desc = descSeprated.split("#");
                String[] data_status = statusSeprated.split("#");
                String[] data_remark = remarkSeprated.split("#");



                for (int i=0; i<data_desc.length ; i++) {



                    apiDetail.setDocEntry(docEntry);
                    apiDetail.setDescription(data_desc[i]);
                    apiDetail.setStatus(data_status[i]);
                    apiDetail.setRemark(data_remark[i]);


                    apiMapper.insertListDetails(apiDetail);
                    sqlSession.commit();




                }



            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            serverResponse.setStatus(ServerResponse.STATUS.OK);
            serverResponse.setData("Record inserted sucessfully");




        }

        responseStr = jsonObjMapper.writeValueAsString(serverResponse);
        response.getWriter().write(responseStr);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (sqlSession != null) {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

(2) This is xml file for database query -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN'
'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd'>

<mapper namespace='com.ti.mappers.InsertListMappers'>
<resultMap type='InsertList' id='InsertListResult'>

    <result property='docEntry' column='DOCENTRY' />
    <result property='description' column='U_DESC' />
    <result property='status' column='U_STATUS' />
    <result property='remark' column='U_REASON' />
    <result property='lineId' column='LINEID' />

  </resultMap>

  <insert id='insertListDetails' parameterType='InsertList'>

    INSERT INTO
    HKCHKREC_L(DOCENTRY, U_DESC, U_STATUS, U_REASON, LINEID)
    VALUES(#{docEntry},#{description},#{status},#{remark},#{lineId})
  </insert>

</mapper>
```